# Onclick event list values ​are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to import a list component to my form and capture the onClick event to submit this information.
But when I click on the list the data comes as undefined. what could I be doing wrong?

This is my list component code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

function Frase({ text, name, options, handleOnChange, value, project }) {
  const [Segmento, SetSegmento] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Segmento</InputLabel>
        <Select onChange={handleOnChange} value={value || ''} displayEmpty>
          {options?.map((Menuitem, index) => (
            <MenuItem  variant = 'selectedMenu' value={Menuitem}  key={Menuitem.id}>
              
              {Menuitem.nome}  
            </MenuItem>

          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Frase;
```

This is my form code:

```
<ListDividers  handleOnChange={handleSegmentos}   options={Segmento} primary={Segmento.nome} key={Segmento.nome}  >
      <ListDividers    key={Segmento.nome} >
        <ListDividers/>
      </ListDividers>
      </ListDividers>

      <SubmitButton text={btnText} />
```

onChande event code:

```
  function handleSegmentos(e) {
        Setproject({...project, Segmento:project.Segmento  });
        ;console.log(project)
          }
```

I've tried changing the onChage properties, putting them in different places within the list tag, but without success

Answer (score 0):

Change your onChange method to:

`function handleSegmentos(e) { Setproject(project => {...project, Segmento:project.Segmento  })}`

Comment: Hello, I performed the test by removing the Console.log but it remains undefined

Comment: Its not an issue because of console log at all. Did you add prevState value : Setproject(project => {...project, ??

Comment: Yes, but the error.

I can only insert a "(" before the project, otherwise the vs code generates an error.

It looked like this:

 function handleSegmentos(e) {
        Setproject (project=> ( {...project, Segmento:project.Segmento }));
        console.log(project)
          }


But still as undefined data